# Combobox dropdown choice freezing

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2016

My combo box (based off of a Query) drops down & shows options but I cannot click on an option & have it stay & fill in its related text boxes! I can highlight a customer in the dropdown but it won't let me "choose" one - all functioning completely stops. I can scroll through all 350 records at the bottom of the Form, but obviously not user-friendly.

Comment: Is the combo box 'unbound'? Is there code behind the `AfterUpdate` event? Am I right in assuming that you want to be able to select an entry in the combo box and have Access move to the chosen record? If the combo box is bound, what you're actually doing is changing the value of this field for the current record. Confirm what you're trying to achieve and I or someone else should be able to help

Comment: @Skippy thx for your reply. Your assumption is correct. The combo box properties reads "Bound Column: 1", but I'm not sure how to change it if that's what's necessary. There is no code behind the AfterUpdate event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so to answer this fully I would need to know some other settings for the combo box. Can you tell me the `Column count` and `Column widths`? You say the combo box is based off a query (so this query is the `Rowsource`), and the `Bound column` is column 1; what is the first column shown in the query? Is it a numeric ID or is it the customer name?

To make the combo box 'unbound' you clear the `Control source` property. If you want to be able to edit the field that this combo was bound to then there are a couple of options, but that's probably a separate question. For now, to achieve the effect of displaying the right record when you change the combo selection, you need to add code to the `AfterUpdate` event:

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst **search criteria**
If Not rst.NoMatch Then
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
End If
Set rst = Nothing
```

Depending on whether the first column of the query that your combo box is based off is numeric or text, you need to replace the **search criteria** with

```
"CustomerID = " & combo1
```

or

```
"CustomerName = '" & combo1 & "'"
```

(but with your own column name and combo box name)

Allen Browne has loads of useful tips on Access databases, check out http://allenbrowne.com/ser-03.html for a more comprehensive answer to this question.